# In the WebRTC source code, how to receive the public network IP and PORT returned by STUN, where in the code, can I change this PORT to a fixed value

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun

In the WebRTC source code, how to receive the public network IP and PORT returned by STUN. Where is it in the code? Can I change this PORT to a fixed value? I can't find it, but I need use a specific port to replace the port that returned by STUN.

Comment: I find the port in stunport.cc line 49, the addr_attr is public network IP PORT, but when I change the port, the ICE is not use my port, and also use the original port. how can I change the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STUN as a protocol will tell the the facts about the network connection. Changing the port returned in the source code will not change those facts.

If you want to control the port e.g. to accomplish something like "outgoing udp traffic needs to happen on port 51234" you will need to run a TURN server on that port.

Comment: But I have another question. where does the webrtc allot port for each network in the source code? (DoAllocate don't allot port) I don't find it.  Is it use the random port to crate socket ? If I change the random port , will it work?

Comment: not necessarily. The NAT may still map the port randomly

Comment: but I want use a fixed port, what can I do?